gain root access to my camera monitor
Edit: I managed to dump the firmware and obtained the root password hash, but there are two hashes. I successfully cracked one, resulting in helpme, but the other one might take a while. However, user:root and passwd:helpme dont works for logging in! What can I do to find that password?
Login Promt:
(none) login: root
Password:
Login incorrect
(none) login:

The Hashes:
root:$1$$.MO09JyxBBNd9Xv0pXIqc0:0:0::/root:/bin/sh
root:ab8nBoH3mb8.g:0:0::/root:/bin/sh

The fist was in passwd but seams broken the second was in passwd- and is ok
I think the easyet way is to just change hast and reflash?
($1$$.MO09JyxBBNd9Xv0pXIqc0 and ab8nBoH3mb8.g)
(ab8nBoH3mb8.g is helpme)
the device is https://www.manualslib.com/products/Tmezon-Mz-Ip-V142b-12387554.html in best case i want to install a basic version of linux or at least get a linux root shell. I loged in to this device via UART. I am prompted to log in, and I've already tried common login credentials, but with no luck. So, I stopped the boot process by spamming a key, and then I got these options:
hisilicon # 
hisilicon # help
?       - alias for 'help'
base    - print or set address offset
bootm   - boot application image from memory
bootp   - boot image via network using BOOTP/TFTP protocol
cmp     - memory compare
cp      - memory copy
crc32   - checksum calculation
ddrp    - ddrp training tools v200
ddrt    - ddr training tools v200
decjpg  - jpgd   - decode jpeg picture.

ext2load- load binary file from a Ext2 filesystem
ext2ls  - list files in a directory (default /)
fatinfo - print information about filesystem
fatload - load binary file from a dos filesystem
fatls   - list files in a directory (default /)
getinfo - print hardware information
go      - start application at address 'addr'
help    - print command description/usage
loadb   - load binary file over serial line (kermit mode)
loady   - load binary file over serial line (ymodem mode)
loop    - infinite loop on address range
md      - memory display
mii     - MII utility commands
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing address)
mtest   - simple RAM read/write test
mw      - memory write (fill)
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
ping    - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network host
printenv- print environment variables
rarpboot- boot image via network using RARP/TFTP protocol
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
saveenv - save environment variables to persistent storage
setenv  - set environment variables
setvobg - setvobg   - set vo backgroud color.
    - setvobg [dev color]
sf      - SPI flash sub-system
showlogo- show logo - start

showupdatalogo- show updata logo - start

startgx - startgx   - open graphics layer.
    - startgx [layer addr stride x y w h]

startvo - startvo   - open interface of vo device.
    - startvo [dev type sync]
stopgx  - stopgx   - close graphics layer.
    - stopgx [layer]
stopvo  - stopvo   - close interface of vo device.
    - stopvo [dev]
tftp    - tftp  - download or upload image via network using TFTP protocol
updata  - updata - start

usb     - USB sub-system
usbboot - boot from USB device
version - print monitor version
hisilicon #  


what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

The term hisilicon can indicate that it bases on a Huawei HiSilicon Kirin chip. For smartphones there is a tutorial: https://github.com/mashed-potatoes/PotatoNV but this seems to require hardware modifications.
